# In Tomcat how can my servlet determine what connectors are configured?

Tags: tomcat

In Tomcat 5.5 the server.xml can have many connectors, typically port only 8080, but for my application a user might configure their servlet.xml to also have other ports open (say 8081-8088).  I would like for my servlet to figure out what socket connections ports will be vaild (During the Servlet.init() tomcat has not yet started the connectors.)

I could find and parse the server.xml myself (grotty), I could look at the thread names (after tomcat starts up - but how would I know when a good time to do that is? )  But I would prefer a solution that can execute in my servlet.init() and determine what will be the valid port range.   Any ideas?   A solution can be tightly bound to Tomcat for my application that's ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Tomcat 6.0 it should be something like:

```
org.apache.catalina.ServerFactory.getServer().getServices
```

to get the services. After that you might use

```
Service.findConnectors
```

which returns a Connector which finally has the method

```
Connector.getPort
```

See the [JavaDocs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector.html) for the details.

Comment: Humm.  Can a servlet access org.apache.catalina.ServerFactory ?  I though that would be in the classloader of the server, and in accessible to the Servlet.

Comment: FYI: I happen to be on Tomcat 5.5.17

Answer (score 0):

Why?

If you need during page generation for a image or css file URL, what's wrong with [ServletRequest.getLocalPort()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalPort()) or, better yet, [HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) for the whole shebang?

Comment: Well, my application has a configureation phase in which different services are hooked up to different ports.  I want to ensure that in the configuration phase, that I can verify that a service is configured to listen on a port that tomcat is accepting connections on.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are about to do - I'd not go down the tomcat specific road.

If you really need to locate different ports, configure them to your webapp through the usual configuration means - e.g. specifying  values. You'd not have any automatic discovery, but also it won't break on tomcats next update.

More specifically, I'd say that I believe you've asked the wrong question. E.g. you have your requirement, opted for one solution and asked for how to implement this solution. I believe you'd get better answers if you stated your first hand requirement and asked for a solution for this.